# Java: How to delete an object from a queue based an a particular attribute?

Tags: java, data-structures, queue

I have to write a program to simulate a queue where students going to the library are given a token and requested to wait for their turns in a logical queue. The token number is automatically generated.

The program should display a menu that allows a user at any time to:

1. Insert a new student in the queue.
2. View the name and token no. of the student at the front of the queue.
3. Delete a student from the queue.
4. Find out how many students there are in the queue.

There should also be an option to exit the program.

I have been able to implement option 1, 2 and 4. Since it hasn't been mentioned as to how the student should be deleted, I suppose the deletion is to be done either by entering the name of the student or the token number but I can't figure out how to do it.

Here is what I have done so far:

**Student.java Class**

```
 package queues;

import java.util.Random;

public class Student {

  private String name;

  private int  tnum;

public Student(String name, int tnum){
    this.name=name;
    this.tnum=tnum;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}


public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}


public int getTnum() {
    return tnum;
}


public void setTnum(int tnum) {
    this.tnum = tnum;
}


public String toString(){
    return "Student name: "+ name+ "  Token num: "+tnum;
   }

 }
```

**Student_Main.java Class**

```
  package queues;

  import java.util.LinkedList;
  import java.util.Queue;
  import java.util.Scanner;

public class Student_Main{


    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);

    int opt;
    int tno;

    Student stdt= new Student("Sophia", 1);
    Student stdt2= new Student("Amelia", 2);
    Student stdt3= new Student("Karxlina", 4);
    Student stdt4= new Student("Rachel", 3);

    Queue<Student> stdtQ= new LinkedList<Student>();

    stdtQ.add(stdt);
    stdtQ.add(stdt2);
    stdtQ.add(stdt3);
    stdtQ.add(stdt4);

    System.out.println(stdtQ);

    while(true){

    System.out.println("Please choose an option. ");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("To insert new student, enter 1.");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("To view the name and token number of a student in front, enter 2.");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("To delete a student, enter 3.");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("To find out the number of students, enter 4.");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("To exit the system, enter 5.");

    opt= sc.nextInt();


    if(opt==1){
        System.out.println("Enter student's name and token number.");
        stdtQ.add(new Student(sc.next(), sc.nextInt()));

        System.out.println("New queue: ");
        System.out.println(stdtQ);
    }



    if(opt==2){
        System.out.println(stdtQ.peek());
    }

    if(opt==3){

    }

    if(opt==4){
        System.out.println("Number of students in the queue is: "+ stdtQ.size());
        System.out.println(stdtQ);
      }

    if(opt==5){
        System.exit(0);
            }


       }

    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(opt==3){             
    System.out.println("Enter token num to delete");
    int to_num = sc.nextInt();
    Iterator<Student> itr = stdtQ.iterator();  

    while(itr.hasNext()){  
        Student obj = itr.next();
        if( obj.getTnum() == to_num)
        {
            stdtQ.remove(obj);
            break;
        }
    }       
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to delete the Student by number (assuming you would have unique number of each student) from queue then you need to implement `equals` method in your student object like:

```
public boolean equals(Object student) {
     ....
     return this.tNum.equals(student.getTnum());
}
```

And if you wish to delete the student by number, you could do something like:

```
if(opt==3){
      //read number
      ((Collection)stdtQ).remove(new Student("", number));
}
```